# How to solve this nonhomogeneous linear second order with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried manipulating this equation to be able to use the Cauchy-Euler method but it didn't work out the way I expected I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this equation, thanks in advance.

$$
xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2e^{2x}
$$

assuming that $$y₁(x)=e^x$$

since the sum of the coefficients is zero that led me to that assumption:

$$x - (1+x) + 1 = 0$$

now we can apply the variation of parameters method and solve for particular and complementary solutions:

$$yc(x)= c₁y₁+ c₂y₂$$
and
$$ yp(x)= u₁y₁+u₂y₂$$
and finally by using the superposition theorem:
$$y(x)= yc(x) + yp(x)$$

Comment: [Hint](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=xy%27%27-%281%2Bx%29y%27+%2B+y+%3D+x%5E2e%5E%282x%29).

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: You could try using the Laplace transform.

Comment: Just apply the mechanism of the method of reduction of order, $y_2(x)=u(x)y_1(x)$, or factor the left side in the obvious way $x(y''-y')-(y'-y)=(xD-1)(D-1)y$, so that setting $y'-y=z$ you get $xz'-z=x^2e^{2x}$, which indeed is of Euler-Cauchy type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rightly guessed that $z_1(x)=e^x$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $$
xz''-(1+x)z'+z=0.
$$
Another one is $z_2(x)=x+1.$

Following the [general method of variation of parameters for a 2nd order linear ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second-order_equation), the solutions of your *normalized* inhomogeneous equation
$$y''-\frac{1+x}xy'+\frac1xy=xe^{2x}$$
will be all the functions of the form
$$y(x):=\lambda(x)z_1(x)+\mu(x)z_2(x)$$
for $\lambda,\mu$ such that
$$\begin{cases}\lambda'(x)z_1(x)+\mu'(x)z_2(x)=0\\\lambda'(x)z'_1(x)+\mu'(x)z'_2(x)=xe^{2x}\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}\lambda'(x)=(x+1)e^x\\\mu'(x)=-e^{2x}.\end{cases}$$
The solutions are therefore ([indeed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=xy%27%27-%281%2Bx%29y%27+%2B+y+%3D+x%5E2e%5E%282x%29), as hinted by @KurtG.)
$$\begin{align}y(x)&=\left(xe^x+\alpha\right)e^x+\left(\frac{-e^{2x}}2+\beta\right)(x+1)\\&=\frac{x-1}2e^{2x}+\alpha e^x+\beta(x+1)\quad(\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R)
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, if we don't guess $z_2$ and take only advantage of your initial guess $z_1$, we can substitute $y(x)=u(x)z_1(x)$ (as indicated by @LutzLehmann) in your inhomogeneous equation, which becomes then:
$$u'=v,\quad xv'+(x-1)v=x^2e^x.$$
A solution of the homogeneous equation $xw'+(x-1)w=0$ is $w(x)=xe^{-x}$ hence the solutions of the inhomogeneous one are
$v(x)=C(x)w(x)$ for $C$ such that $C'(x)=e^{2x},$ i.e.
$$v(x)=\left(\frac{e^{2x}}2-\beta\right)xe^{-x},$$
which results successively in
$$u(x)=\frac{x-1}2e^x+\beta(x+1)e^{-x}+\alpha$$
and again:
$$y(x)=\frac{x-1}2e^{2x}+\alpha e^x+\beta(x+1)\quad(\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R).$$